# Share files with navigator.share in PWA on IOS

Tags: ios, share, progressive-web-apps

The attached code works perfectly on Android, even old versions, and doesn't work on IOS (tested on Safari 13).
If you try to share on Whatsapp, on android it also shares the photo, on iphone only text.
Where am I wrong?
Codepen: https://codepen.io/michitkt/pen/YzqBbxo

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, minimal-ui">
</head><body>
<button disabled="disabled">click me</button>
<div class="result"></div>
<script>

fetch('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/87/F-15C_53FS_36FW_Aviano_1993.jpeg/1920px-F-15C_53FS_36FW_Aviano_1993.jpeg')
    .then(function(response) {
        console.log("response",response);
        response.blob().then(function(myBlob) {
            console.log("blob",myBlob);
            var file = new File([myBlob], "test.jpg", {type: 'image/jpeg'});
            //alert("file: "+file.name+", size "+file.size);
            productFilesArray = [file];
            console.log("array file",productFilesArray);
            btn.removeAttribute("disabled");
        });
    });

const btn = document.querySelector('button');
const result = document.querySelector('.result');

btn.addEventListener('click', async () => {
    if (navigator.share) {
        try {
            await navigator.share({
                title: 'Sharing',
                text: 'Learn web development on MDN!',
                url: 'https://developer.mozilla.org',
                files: productFilesArray
            })
            result.textContent = 'Starting sharing';
        } catch(err) {
            result.textContent = 'Error: ' + err;
        }
    } else {
        result.textContent = 'You can\'t share';
    }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not sure but i think this example uses web share api level 2 that only chrome 75+ supports.

Answer (score 0):

Everybody can have BUGS!

Your code is fine. Just remove everything Except the {files:...}. Then BOOM!

Following is the code snippet for you.

```
if (navigator.share) {
    try {
        await navigator.share({
            files: productFilesArray
        })
        result.textContent = 'Starting sharing';
    } catch(err) {
        result.textContent = 'Error: ' + err;
    }
} else {
    result.textContent = 'You can\'t share';
}
```

Comment: I need to add a link to the file, I can't remove it from code

Comment: Understood, recently I found this bug/issue then did some experiment and got the solution for my online service.

May be you can try little bit more experiment if you can find any workaround to include the link for you.

My theory is that WhatsApp only except one(1) / single item from external source(s). 

Like the way 
      https://wa.me/?text=blahblah 
works.

That's why if you only include files then it accepts from external source.

Answer (score 0):

```
// is file share supported
if (navigator.canShare && navigator.canShare({ files: filesArray })) {
  navigator.share({
    files: filesArray,
    title: 'Vacation Pictures',
    text: 'Photos from September 27 to October 14.',
  })
  .then(() => console.log('Share was successful.'))
  .catch((error) => console.log('Sharing failed', error));
} else {
  console.log(`Your system doesn't support sharing files.`);
}
```

As of early 2021, using the API to share title, text, and URL is supported by:

- Safari 12 or later on macOS and iOS.
- Chrome 75 or later on Android, and 89 or later on Chrome OS and Windows.

Using the **API to share files** is supported by:

- Safari 15 or later on macOS and iOS.
- Chrome 75 or later on Android, and 89 or later on Chrome OS and Windows.
  (Most Chromium-based browsers, like Edge, have the same support for this feature as the corresponding version of Chrome.)

Comment: Yes but sharing files with text and url is the problem. It works now?

Comment: Your problem is very clear, it is not possible to use this feature in safari 13. I shared how to detect and handle this situation.

Sharing files with text and url not possible in IOS 15 (15-10-2021). 

Sharif's answer is correct if you want to use this feature in Safari 15. However, you can only share files(without text/tile/url).

In short: there's nothing you can do until Apple fixes this situation.